# Why were these mods done?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, repair

I have a "Quantum Data 882E-HDMI Video Generator" in for repair. It has a fault or two, but also has number of mods which I would help with.

### Questions regarding board "84-00221 Rev B/99-00581 B":

Photos: 20230302_192356.jpg & 20230302_195856.jpg

1. Any clues why this mod was done?
   I have drawn two simple schematics see: Screenshot_20230303_200550.png).
   The schematic on the left shows what I think the original circuit looked like.
   The schematic on the right shows what I think the circuit is now.
   If U24 is a SN74CB3Q3345PWR, then the mods don't make any sense to me.
2. Are my schematics correct?
3. Have I identified U24 correctly.
4. What is the component above U24 and next to the the resistor (which I think is R59)? and what do the markings mean?

Photo: 20230302_194930.jpg

1. Any clues why the mods to the pins of BTB connector (below U3) were done?
2. Why was the track going from pin 3P to component U4 cut?
3. then the jumpered to pin 2C?
4. Why is pin 3P now jumpered to TP1 pin 7?

### Questions regarding main board:

Photo: 20230302_194631.jpg:

1. Any clues why the mod to U6 was done?
       The mod is a resistor from pin 20 of U6 to a via.

20230302_192356.jpg
[image: 20230302_192356.jpg]

20230302_194423.jpg
[image: 20230302_194423.jpg]

20230302_194426.jpg
[image: 20230302_194426.jpg]

20230302_194631.jpg
[image: 20230302_194631.jpg]

20230302_194930.jpg
[image: 20230302_194930.jpg]

20230302_195856.jpg
[image: 20230302_195856.jpg]

Screenshot_20230303_200550.png
[image: Screenshot_20230303_200550.png]

Comment: Does the /OE port ohm out to anywhere? Its essential to know how this is operating.

Comment: Photo 194930 is missing.

Comment: I’m loving the sideways chip resistor, definitely gonna use that one in the future.